# How to select php filter and downloading file with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to select the filter for "pitchers" and download to Excel from here: https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/stats.php

I've tried the following but am getting an error/don't sure how to select the necessary items

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/stats.php")
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'filter-tab is-selected')]")
```

Ideally (for now), the script runs and downloads the file locally.

Comment: click this XPATH: "//div[@data-title='P')]"... then click this XPATH: "//button[@class='export-button is-excel']"

Answer (score 0):

This downloads the pitcher data. It seems that there is some type of hidden html in the website. That's why the code finds the entire table first, then the excel button.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/stats.php")
pitchers = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-name='P']")
pitchers.click()

player_stats_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-pos='p']")))
excel_download = WebDriverWait(player_stats_elem, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//img[@alt='Excel']/..")))
excel_download.click()
```